# Should I not be using MobileMouse with Tor?

Tags: security

Wondering if the application will deanonymize web by communication with my iphone on clearnet ip.

Comment: At the moment it is unclear to me what you are asking about. Could elaborate a bit? What is MobileMouse, what do you know about, how can it be used etc.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is not recommended to use any software that wasn't specifically analyzed for safety/application leaks if you need anonymity from it. MobileMouse has not been analyzed in this regard yet.